# SSRS report - get data from API

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I need to show data in a report from an API. I am putting together a very simple XML query. Here is my Data source:

```
Connection type: XML
Connection string: http://localhost:5000/runNodeScript
```

Dataset:

```
<Query>
    <Method Name="runNodeScript" Namespace="http://localhost:5000/runNodeScript" />
</Query>
```

I am getting an error:
[image]

Any idea what to do next?

Thanks

I have changed the method to accept POST and I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem at most part is that  a dataset needs to be created first. I also had to modify data source a bit. Here it is:

```
http://localhost:5000/endpoint?type=xml
```

dataset would have no query, just fields. The Most important thing is that the endpoint should be sending back an xml with Base64 string as a value of an element. Then in report in order to show the image I use this:

```
=Convert.FromBase64String(First(Fields!nameofbase64elementname.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

After that it worked like a charm.